VLC doesn't see chaptered video's chapters
I installed a video from Youtube and goaled watch it on VLC with chapters like on Youtube. For this i maked a metadata file for FFMPEG
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=0
END=118000
title=Introduction
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=118000
END=170000
title=What is Bootstrap?
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=170000
END=321000
title=Why use Bootstrap?
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=321000
END=582000
title=Download compiled CSS and JS
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=582000
END=700000
title=Install via CDN
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=700000
END=900000
title=NPM installation
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=900000
END=2221000
title=Grid System
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=2221000
END=2545000
title=Buttons
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=2545000
END=3473000
title=Cards
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=3473000
END=4357000
title=Typography
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=4357000
END=4709000
title=Responsive images
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=4709000
END=5872000
title=Utilities
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=5872000
END=6104000
title=Tables
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=6104000
END=6608000
title=Alerts
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=6608000
END=7498000
title=Navs & Navbars
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=7498000
END=7754000
title=Icons
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=7754000
END=8454000
title=Forms
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=8454000
END=9030000
title=Other components
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=9030000
END=9031000
title=Let's build a webpage!

And i entered to terminal this code (i abbreviated video file names with hiding and i abbreviated terminal code with not writing folder name):
ffmpeg -i videofile.mp4 -i FFMETADATAFILE -map_metadata 1 -codec copy video.mp4

It gived me same video with a slight difference larger size. I opened it in VLC. But VLC didn't give any chapter information. Why?..
> ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -f ffmetadata FFMETADATAFILE.txt

;FFMETADATA1
major_brand=isom
minor_version=512
compatible_brands=isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder=Lavf61.1.100

Video with a slight difference larger than original file but after extract his metadata there is no information about chapters.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

isnt that obvious? Can a real user answer this?

I found the solution. It should has free lines.
Like this:
;FFMETADATA1
title=Adding Chapters using FFMPEG
artist=You

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=0
END=118000
title=Introduction

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=118000
END=170000
title=What is Bootstrap?

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=170000
END=321000
title=Why use Bootstrap?

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=321000
END=582000
title=Download compiled CSS and JS

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=582000
END=700000
title=Install via CDN

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=700000
END=900000
title=NPM installation

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=900000
END=2221000
title=Grid System

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=2221000
END=2545000
title=Buttons

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=2545000
END=3473000
title=Cards

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=3473000
END=4357000
title=Typography

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=4357000
END=4709000
title=Responsive images

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=4709000
END=5872000
title=Utilities

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=5872000
END=6104000
title=Tables

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=6104000
END=6608000
title=Alerts

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=6608000
END=7498000
title=Navs & Navbars

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=7498000
END=7754000
title=Icons

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=7754000
END=8454000
title=Forms

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=8454000
END=9030000
title=Other components

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=9030000
END=9031000
title=Let's build a webpage!

